# Replace NA by max value in column in a list of data frames

Tags: r, lapply, na

I have two data frames and two questions. In both data frames df1 and df2, I can replace the NAs by 0.

df1

```
 var1 <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, 4, 5, 5)
 var2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
 df1 <- data.frame(var1, var2)
 df1$var1[is.na(df1$var1)] <- 0
```

df2

```
 var1 <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, 4, 5, 9)
 var2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
 df2 <- data.frame(var1, var2)
 df2$var1[is.na(df1$var1)] <- 0
```

But how would this work if I wanted to replace the NAs by the maximum value of var1 rather than 0? I thought it would be the following but it does not work.

```
 df1$var1[is.na(df1$var1)] <- max(df1$var1)
```

Once this is solved, I would actually like to do this for a list of data frames using *lapply*.

```
 mylist <- list(df1, df2)
```

My idea was something like the following - which does not work either.

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) x$var1[is.na(x$var1)] <- max(x$var1))
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use `na.rm=TRUE` in `max`:

```
>  df1$var1[is.na(df1$var1)] <- max(df1$var1, na.rm=TRUE)
> 
> 
>  var1 <- c(1, NA, 2, NA, 4, 5, 9)
>  var2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
>  df2 <- data.frame(var1, var2)
>  df2$var1[is.na(df1$var1)] <-  max(df2$var1, na.rm=TRUE)
> df1
  var1 var2
1    1    1
2    5    2
3    2    3
4    5    4
5    4    5
6    5    6
7    5    7
> df2
  var1 var2
1    1    1
2   NA    2
3    2    3
4   NA    4
5    4    5
6    5    6
7    9    7
```

You attempt with the `lapply` missed the fact that you would need to make the modified dataframe the last object evaluated. The results of `[<-` is just the item and not the full dataframe:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) {x$var1[is.na(x$var1)] <- max(x$var1, na.rm=TRUE); x})
```

Comment: This works, thank you @42- for the corrected code and the explanation on `lapply`. There was a typo in my question in `df2`. It should have been `df2$var1[is.na(df2$var1)] <- 0`. Therefore, `df2$var1[is.na(df2$var1)] <-  max(df2$var1, na.rm=TRUE)`.